# How to create new rows in a dataframe based on another row's contents with the same values but in different order?

Tags: r, newline, na

I would like to transform my dataset in a way that for each original row, all the values within it becomes the first one in a new row, while keeping the other values.

I'm not sure this explanation is clear so here is an example:
let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
V1          V2            V3       V4          V5         V6
valve      valves       VALVE      VALVES      Valve     Valves
vaporizer  vaporizers   Vaporizer  Vaporizers   NA        NA
```

And I would like

```
V1          V2            V3       V4          V5         V6
valve      valves       VALVE      VALVES      Valve       Valves
valves     valve        VALVE      VALVES      Valve       Valves
VALVE      valves       valve      VALVES      Valve       Valves
VALVES     valves       VALVE      valve       Valve       Valves
Valve      valves       VALVE      VALVES      valve       Valves
Valves     valves       VALVE      VALVES      Valve       valve
vaporizer  vaporizers   Vaporizer  Vaporizers    NA          NA
vaporizers vaporizer    Vaporizer  Vaporizers    NA          NA
Vaporizer  vaporizers   vaporizer  Vaporizers    NA          NA
Vaporizers vaporizers   Vaporizer  vaporizer     NA          NA
```

This means taking into account the fact that there are NAs (and not to create a new line when there are some).

I've been struggling a lot with this issue since 2 days, thus any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at this. First I made a function that switches columns in the way you desire. Then I applied this to the data by ROW. The output of `apply` is a list so I used `do.call(rbind,listobject)` to stitch it back together:

```
# data
dat <- data.frame(V1 = c("valve","vaporizer"), V2 = c("valves","vaporizers"), 
                  V3 = c("VALVE","Vaporizer"), V4 = c("VALVES","Vaporizers"), 
                  V5 = c("Valve",NA), V6 = c("Valves",NA), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

# function
musicalchairs <- function(x){
  y <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = sum(!is.na(x)), ncol = length(x)))
  y[1,] <- x
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(!is.na(x[i])){
      y[i+1,] <- c(y[1,i+1], y[i,-(i+1)])
    }
  }
  y[1:sum(!is.na(x)),]
}

# desired output
do.call(rbind, apply(dat, 1, musicalchairs))
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Did this answer your question?